# Beginner problems with Excel Macro VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question about Excel.

I have a sheet with some columns, like:

```
A         B         C
------------------------   
1   test    1
2   test    5
3   test    5
4   test    2
4   test    6
5   test    7
6   test    8
7   test    2
8   test    3
9   test    3
9   test    1
9   test    4
10  test    5
```

I would like a macro that does the following. It checks C. If value of C is lower than 3, copy that row and all the following rows with the same value in A, until A changes, to a new sheet, Then check C again and so on.

Output here should be:

A new sheet with

```
a b c

4 test 2
4 test 6
7 test 2
9 test 1
9 test 4
```

Can anyone please help me with that?

Comment: You say "help" but without any code of your own it looks like you just want someone to write it for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I've found it (haven t really tested it yet)

```
Sub CustomcCopy()
Dim controleValue As Double
controleValue = 3
Dim AValue As String
Dim lastline As Integer, tocopy As Integer

lastline = Range("F65536").End(xlUp).Row
j = 1

For i = 1 To lastline
    For Each c In Range("L" & i)
        If (c < controleValue And c > 0) Then
            tocopy = 1
        End If
    Next c
    If tocopy = 1 Then
    AValue = Cells(i, "A").Value

    Do While Cells(i, "A").Value = AValue

        Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets(2).Rows(j)
        j = j + 1
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    End If
tocopy = 0
Next i

End Sub
```